# how to keep button text the same when switching fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I have a program with several fragments in one activity. The menu fragment lets the user switch to one of the other fragment layouts. I have many buttons on the menu fragment layout that change text when pressed.

I want this text to remain the same when I navigate back from one of the other fragments but it goes back to its default text while the spinners hold their position. Since the fragment only stopped not destroyed I thought the buttons would hold there text? Sorry if it's something obvious, I'm new to programming.

here is some out my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options_menu, container, false);

Channel0    = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Channel0);
OpenChannel0 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Channel0Open);

         OpenChannel0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if ( OpenChannel0.getText().equals("Open") )
            {
                Channel0Spinner.setEnabled(false);
                OpenChannel0.setText("Close");
                String text = Channel0Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Channel0.setText("Channel 0 ("+ text +")");

            else
            {
                Channel0Spinner.setEnabled(true);
                OpenChannel0.setText("Open");
            }

        }
    });

    Channel0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    f = new Channel0frag();

    FragmentTransaction frag = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    frag.replace(R.id.container, f);
    frag.addToBackStack(null);
    frag.commit();
            }
        }

    });
```

So when I navigate back from Channel0frag, I want buttons Channel0 and OpenChannel0 to keep whatever text is set.

UPDATE:

When I enter the following code in the onResume method, it still outputs the original button text when I navigate back from another fragment even though the spinner does not lose its position. Why is Channel0 button text not getting assigned to the text displayed in the spinner?

```
    String text = Channel0Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Channel0.setText("Channel 0 ("+ text +")");
```

Comment: try overriding `onResume` method and set text for button there

Comment: But the button text is changed when the button is clicked, I thought since the buttons are assigned in onCreate they would not be instantiated again as only onStart and onResume  is called when the fragment is restarted? It gives an error when I try to assign the buttons to the layout in onResume.... (cannot resolve method) findViewById

Comment: could you share your code

Comment: code is added now @mgokgoz

Comment: Have one boolean in activity, set it true when text is set to "open" and vice versa, and set text in onResume by checking its value.

Comment: Don't use text equalization while on click, use a `boolean` instead. For `onResume` method, you don't have to `findViewById` again, make your buttons global for that view and initiate at `onCreateView` and, use `setText` method on `onResume` method.

Comment: that will work for the open, close buttons but button Channel0 can have many different pieces of text. I tried setting text for Channel0 in onResume  as the position on the spinner is saved but it does not work?

Comment: how do you make buttons global?

Comment: should I use Shared Preferences then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Created a boolean variable and set it to true then OpenChannel0 button text was "Open" and checked the state of it and set the button text in onResume. For OpenChannel0 I used Shared Preferences to save the text state as there was several different text states for this button.

Answer (score 0):

maintain global variable in your application class and override onResume on fragment class.

Comment: did not think there was such thing as a global variable in android programming?